# How to deploy a simple HTML/CSS/JS page to heroku, netlify

Tags: javascript, html, css, heroku, deployment

I am new on this.
I just finished my personal web using html, css and js. Saved on a github repository withut problems
but i dont really knwo how to deploy it in a server.

[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiUpT.png)

Comment: Do you want it to be hosted on a website other than GitHub?

Comment: yes but i dont know how to do it because i think github works only as repository

Comment: So basically you want all your website’s files to be moved into another domain, preferably for free.

Comment: For example this is what i want: to click on link and open as a webpage "https://git.heroku.com/ander-portfolio.git" i linked github to heroku but it doesn work

Comment: "Heroku | Welcome to your new app!
Refer to the documentation if you need help deploying."
this is what i get when click

Comment: I’m not sure how to use heroku but I could direct you towards a hosting website

Comment: I mean if I need an extra file to be able to deploy this project

Comment: Just check out somee.com. I use it.

Comment: @Matthias thanks man it was really useful. just deployed my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using somee.com to host your website because it is free and easy. Just go to https://somee.com to begin. Another good website to use is https://glitch.com which is also good but the file manager is not as good.